# Setting a property of type T using a variable of type T', and handling the conversion in the setter?

Tags: c#, properties, type-conversion, setter

Let's say I have a class with a public property inside, like this:

```
class Data
{
    public int Property { get; set; }
}
```

Now, for some reason, I would want to pass a string to this property. I could convert the string to an `Int32` before passing it but being lazy is easier. Is it possible to change the setter so that the conversion is automatically done ? As in:

```
if (value is string) Property = Int32.Parse(value);
```

Of course, this example doesn't work. VS throws an error plus a warning about how value will never be string.

EDIT: yep, I know this is a bad idea. This is simply curiosity.

Comment: No, that's not possible.  Nor is it a good idea.

Comment: I never said it was a good idea, it was pure curiosity.

Comment: To make sure I understand your question, you realize that `value` will never be anything but an `int` in the setter, but you'd like to be able to pass any value to `Data.Property` and handle the conversions after the fact rather than *a priori*? Did you mean to use `object`?

Comment: @pikzen - He never said you said it was a good idea. He was just trying to give you extra information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change the setter in this manner.  The setter of a property in C# must have the same type as the property itself.  There is no way to insert a static conversion from any other type as a function of the setter.

Comment: Well, thank you. It would have surprised me if it were possible, actually.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the conversions, you could create setter methods, instead of using the property setter:

```
void SetProperty(int value);
void SetProperty(String value);
```

And so on.

If you *really* want to go wild, you could create a `PropertyValue` type with implicit conversions from ints, strings and whatever types you want, and use that as the property type. It'll make the setter behave like you want, but you're going to have a problem with the getter. If you really want to save those conversions, use the first solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, per the language specification if you declare a property as some type `T`, then `value` will be guaranteed to be `T` (or one of its derived types or a type which implements the interface `T`) at compile time.

If you would like your setter to receive values of any type, use `object`:

```
private int prop;

public object Property
{
    get { return this.prop; }
    set
    {
        this.prop = value != null ? Int32.Parse(value.ToString()) : 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a property of the type `object`:

```
class Data {
  private int _property;
  public object Property {
    get {
      return _property;
    }
    set {
      if (value is string) {
        _property = Int32.Parse(value);
      } else {
        _property = (int)value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't very practical, though. When you assing an `int` to the property it will be imlicitly boxed in an `object`, and then unboxed. When you get the value the getter returns the `int` boxed in an `object`, so you have to unbox (cast) it if you want it as an `int` value.